# Transferring values first empty column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe as follows:

| ID | c1 | c 2 | c3 | c4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 3 |  | 6 |
| 2 | 1 |  |  |  |
| 3 |  | 8 | 1 | 9 |
| 4 | 1 |  | 10 |  |

I'm looking for a way to add these numbers together as far left as possible. In the example, my desired output would be

| ID | c1 | c 2 | c3 | c4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 6 |  |  |
| 2 | 1 |  |  |  |
| 3 | 8 | 1 | 9 |  |
| 4 | 1 | 10 |  |  |

How would I be able to do that? The transferring could also be to new columns, not necessarily the existing ones. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post your sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function should do it:

```r
mytable <- as.data.frame(t(apply(mytable,1, function(x) { return(c(x[!is.na(x)],x[is.na(x)]))})))
```